# How to Inject spring objects into cordaApp project?

Tags: corda

I Created a small spring library and I wanted to integrate it in CorDapp project.

I added all required spring dependencies in CorDapp build gradle  but when I run the Application , my @Autowired classes are getting as null.

Can anybody help in this regard or anybody tried this kind of functionality before ?

In short  I wanted to inject spring objects into cordaApp project , is it possible ??

<<<<<<<<<< Below is the Code Sample >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

ExampleApi class contains "metoo" a REST API and is a annotated with @Component and also having `TestComp` as `@Autowired`:

```
@Path("example")
@Component
public class ExampleApi {
    private final CordaRPCOps rpcOps;
    private final CordaX500Name myLegalName;

    public ExampleApi(CordaRPCOps rpcOps) {
        this.rpcOps = rpcOps;
        this.myLegalName = rpcOps.nodeInfo().getLegalIdentities().get(0).getName();
    }

    @Autowired
    TestComp testComp;

    @GET
    @Path("metoo")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String whoamitest() {
        // here testComp is getting null at runtime
        return testComp.getMyName();
    }
}
```

===================================================================

Example TestComp Class is like below:

```
@Component
public class TestComp {

    public String getMyName()  {
        return "Hello there ...";
    }
}
```

===================================================================

Added Application class as below in com.example package

Added JerseyConfig class like mention below:

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("com.example");
        register(ExampleApi.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/*");
        // our rest resources will be available in the path /rest/*
        registration.addInitParameter(
        ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, 
        JerseyConfig.class.getName());
        return registration;
    }
}
```

============================================================

Added below libraries/ dependencies in build.gradle file:

```
compile (group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jersey', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'){
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

compile(group: 'org.springframework.boot',name: 'spring-boot-starter-web' , version: '1.5.9.RELEASE') {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}

compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE'
```

=================================================================

Added below thing into outer build.gradle file:

```
classpath group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-parent', version: '1.5.9.RELEASE', ext: 'pom'
```

==================================================================

Comment: Can you provide of example of what you're trying to autowire?

Comment: E.g. we have CordaNetworkService custom defined class which lists all basic/common operations related to network like 
 1. getPeers()   2. getPeersWithNotaries()  3. getNetworkMapService()
 4. checkIfNotaryParty()  5. getPartyCountOnNetwork()  and many more ..
 We kept these common/ generic methods separate in the spring library so that it can be pluggable to any of our corda project easily , 
 and that will help us to develop cordaApp in less time.

Comment: I think the issue is , corda using Jax-rs [@Path] for Rest functionality and when we start corda Node its context and our spring lib context is conflicting.
 Any idea or example for this type of functionality will be helpful.

Comment: Can you please link to a repo replicating the problem? I'm unable to replicate it.

Comment: getting below error org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringComponentProvider initia
SEVERE: Spring context lookup failed, skipping spring component provider initialization.

Comment: I think its because spring context is not getting set properly in this project.

Answer (score 2):

This structure simply can't work:

- On the one hand, you're defining `ExampleApi` and listing it in your CorDapp's web plugin registry. This means that the API will be picked up at compile time and converted into a set of endpoints for the default node webserver, which is a Jetty webserver
- On the other hand, you're defining a standalone Spring webserver

These two webservers are running as completely separate Java processes, and therefore one cannot inject `Autowired` classes in the other.